# Xsl-fo accessing attribute value from xml and applying fo inline transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, xsl-fo

I trying to apply the styles by accessing the attribute values of xml files, kindly refer the sample xml below and advice to use the xsl,

for example if the attribute value is bold for  element,  should must be with bold style. Please help.

```
<main>
    <reference>
        <p>This is bold attribute <style type="bold">Sample 1</style></p>
        <p>This is italic attribute <style type="italic">Sample 1</style></p>
    </reference>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the style information to something usable in FO formatting:

```
<xsl:template match="style">
    <fo:inline>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@type='bold'">
                <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@type='italic'">
                <xsl:attribute name="font-style">italic</xsl:attribute>
```

etc.

Comment: Or better with specific templates like xsl:template match="style[@type='bold']" or even deeper and only match on @type like above and throw attributes ... so many ways to skin that cat